# Match part of a file path with regex

Tags: regex

Using regex I need to extract part of a UNC path. 
Example:

- \server\share\folder1\subfolder1
- \server\share\folder1\subfolder1\subfolder2
- \server\share\complex\subfolder1
- \server\share\5555AB12\subfolder1\subfolder2\subfolder3

I need to get the value after the share, so in this example i need to get:

- folder1
- complex
- 5555AB12

The \server\share\ is always the same, but the number of subfolders can vary.
I've tried different regex examples and working from those, but I just don't get it...

I've tried some regex with a regex tester, when I find a code where my result is in a group, I don't know how to use that specific group.

`.*\\(\w\S+)\\(\w\S+)`  gives a subfolder, not what I need

Comment: just a hint in addition to the already given answer: (not only) the quantifier `*` is very greedy, i.e. that it tries to match as often as possible. to avoid this especially when in use with `.` one should place a `?` behind the quantifier, e.g. `*?`, so that it stops when it reaches the pattern behind itself: `.*?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex and capture your value from group1.

```
\bshare\\([^\\]+)
```

Here, `\bshare` matches share as exact word followed by `\` and capture one or more characters other than `\` what follows after.

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eBLKJv/1)**

Comment: This works, I had to change the path because it's case sensitive but good results after this.

Comment: @Qook: Please consider accepting the answer if it helped you. You also get +2 reputation points and help other users locating this answer easily.